# lotus notes queryopen auto start option

Tags: lotus-notes

in **lotus notes 6.5.6** when i switch from *view1* to *view2* or when i only select a document in a view lotus notes execute automatically the *queryopen* statement of the selected document. why ?

**this happens only in one host if my company** so i think is a option of:

> notes.ini
>
> user pref
>
> other setting

but i cannot find where is set...

there is someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Frameset with a frame called "NotesPreview" and this frame is "open" (even if it is only one pixel high) in that one client, then the document will be opened in preview, when the cursor switches to it, and then QueryOpen- event will be triggered.

Comment: yes, you are right ! but i use only navigator. i add to my notes.ini the line $ShowOrHidePreviewPane=0 and in the post open of all db i add @Command([ShowHidePreviewPane]; @TextToNumber(@Environment("ShowOrHidePreviewPane")))

Comment: this method hide preview pane every time a db is open... there is a method to completly disable/remove the preview pane ?

Comment: To completely disable / remove preview pane, you need at least Designer- access and a designer client. Be aware: Navigators are not used since Notes 4.x, in version 5 they were replaced by framesets. If your database still uses navigators, then its design is >10 years old... Even 6.5 is end of life since April 2010...

Comment: it's ok, i have designer access and designer client... what i have to do ?

Comment: Unfortunately if you keep the "navigators", then there is NO WAY to disable preview pane, at least no, that I can remember, as the last version using Navigators was 4.6 and that was stopped in 2000. So you would have to redo the navigators and replace them with Framesets / Pages / Outlines.. To much work to handle that in StackOverflow

Comment: it's ok, I know how to use frameset/pages/outlines...  thank you !

Comment: You might want to take a look at this old blog post that I wrote years ago, covering the topic of detecting whether the preview pane is open.  I'm not sure if any of the techniques I mention will work in a queryOpen event, but maybe it will give you some ideas: http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/d6plinks/RSCZ-6SC64R